# problems installing tensorflow from python

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, failed-installation

when i'm trying to install Tensorflow, this comes up, what shall i do??

```
C:\Users\39348>pip install tensorflow
    Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    **ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow**
```

Comment: Run Command Line as Administrator.  (Right click, Run as Administrator)

Comment: shall i do it in the cmd?

Comment: Is that not where you were doing it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps that you have followed to install tensorflow? Also, may i know version of TF, Python and PIP? Thanks!